# regex using Sublime

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

Using my text editor of choice, Sublime 2, I want to search through code that has uncommented alerts. So I need a regex for that finds "alert" but not "//alert" or "// alert". I don't know how to invert and then combine the two results. Sublime Text uses the Boost syntax for regular expressions. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Since there maybe more than one space between the `\\` and `alert` you could use a regex search which supports variable width lookaheads tool outside the text editor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can search for text not preceeded by `//`, thus

```
(?<!\/\/\s?)alert
```

EDIT:
If the editor doesn't support variable lookbehinds you must specify all the possibilities in different lookbehinds

```
(?<!\/\/\s)(?<!\/\/)alert
```

Comment: I'd like to say that works, but Sublime says invalid lookbehind assertion encountered. Variable length lookbehind isn't supported in Boost

Comment: +1 for using `\s` instead of just space character. Escaping `/` may not be necessary.

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
(?<!//)(?<!// )alert
```

Boost syntax is based on Pearl RegExp. Thus negative lookbehind `(?<!text)` should be supported. In this example I use the negative lookbehind twice (with and without space) because the lookbehind text has to be fixed length.

you can read more about lookaraound feature in RegExp here:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html